# Cocoa - NSThread and First Responder

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, nsthread

When I start a 2nd background thread and pause the main thread, will my First Responder still be in action? For example I have an overwriting method called -flagsChanged and was wondering if it would still be active if the main thread is offline.

Thanks,

Kevin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don’t pause the main thread since [the main thread is responsible for handling events](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html) and your application UI will become irresponsive. If the main thread is paused, it won’t handle events, hence it won’t dispatch key events to the first responder.

If you think you need to pause the main thread, you probably need to redesign your program so that the behaviour that requires sleeping (if it does require sleeping) is offset to a secondary thread. If you need to update the user interface from a secondary thread, you should use `-performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`.